# Limitations of eval()?

Tags: python, eval

Why is this?

```
>>> eval(str(17*3))
51
>>> t=17;t*3
51
>>> eval(str(t=17;t*3))
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    eval(str(t=17;t*3))
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Is there a way to send eval() variables?

```
>>> z=input("ins: ");cxc=compile(z,'<string>','exec');y=eval(cxc);print(y)
ins: t=17;t+3
None
>>>
```

I should have been more precise, I thought once I was helped with a good answer it would be universal.  But lo, this is my actual use case attempting @cnicutar suggestion.

```
>>> z=input("ins: ");y=eval(z);print(y)
ins: 't*13+q', {'q':4,'t':2}
('t*13+q', {'q': 4, 't': 2})
>>>
```

Trying @LtWorf and @Ghopper21 's implementation.

Comment: Also note that str(17*3) is '51', not '17*3'. You probably meant to pass string literals to eval.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `compile`:

```
>>> expr = compile('t = 42; print(t)', '<string>', 'exec')
>>> eval(expr)
42
```

Comment: Of course the answer is 42. :D

Comment: >>> z=input("ins: ");cxc=compile(z,'<string>','exec');y=eval(cxc);print(y)
ins: 17+55
None

Comment: I always thought Adams would explain that there was a bug in the first run of the computations.  The second time around they realised it was 17.

Comment: Douglas Adams did explain it. When Deep Thought  presented the answer, to life, the universe and everything, it noted that there was an overflow error during the calculation.  When Arthur produced the question (8 episodes later in the radio play available free online!) by randomly picking Scrabble tiles it was, "What is six times eight."

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can send `eval` variables using a dictionary as the second (and third) arguments. These arguments are documented [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval). Here's your example:

```
>>> eval('t*3', {'t': 17})
51
```

Incidentally, the specific error you are getting is not because `eval` can't take a statement assigning variables as it's first parameter (although indeed it cannot); it's because the parameter to `str` needs to be an expression, which can't assign variables, not a statement, which can. Notice you'll get the same error with just `str`:

```
>>> str(t=17;t*3)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    str(t=17;t*3)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

EDIT: As for your specific use case, the problem you have there is that the input string

```
 't*13+q', {'q':4,'t':2}
```

gets evaluated (by `input`, which reads in a string and calls `eval` on it) into a so-called "tuple," i.e. a combination of multiple expressions into a single expression, due to the presence of the comma. You can't evaluate a tuple. (Your use case example actually should return an error -- not sure why it isn't.)

To fix this, you need to "unpack" the tuple so `eval` knows which part of the tuple is the expression you want to evaluate (the first part, with the string expression `t*13+q`, i.e. `z[0]`) and which is the dictionary of variable values (the second part, with the dictionary `{'q':4,'t':2}`, i.e. `z[1]`), i.e. replace `y=eval(z)` with

```
y = eval(z[0], z[1])
```

Alternatively (and more Pythonically), you can tell Python to automatically unpack the tuple into consecutive parameters to a function using the asterisk syntax, i.e. replace `y=eval(z)` with

```
y = eval(*z)
```

Comment: >>> z=input("ins: ");y=eval(x);print(y)
ins: 't*3', {'t': 17}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object
>>>

Comment: @Peregrine -- see edit with answer for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can also:

```
>>> t = 17
>>> print eval('t*3')
51
```

Answer (score 0):

```
eval(source[, globals[, locals]]) -> value
```

you can also pass a dictionary containing like {'a'=0,'b'=1} and so on...

for example:

```
eval('t*13+q', {'q':4,'t':2})
```

Comment: I'm sorry would you mind giving an example.  I could better understand if you showed an example to go with your universal description.

Comment: edited to add an example

Comment: Thanks, but I added my actual use case to my question, and this syntax fails under those circumstances. ...that is, x=input("ins: ");eval(x)  >>>ins: 't*13+q', {'q':4,'t':2})

Comment: In an expression you cannot assign variables, you can only pass a dictionary with the variables as 2nd parameter.